# Asp.net MVC Controller Index method doesn't fire on Redirect from another controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var tickets =
            DependencyContainer.DomainController.ShowTickets();
        if(tickets==null)
        {
            ViewData.Add("Error","Associate not found");
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");//Doesn't fire the index?
        }
        return View();
```

Home controller method is as follows and only fires on the debugger startup, and after the redirect IF I hit F5.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to Home Loans and Insuring Technology Ticketing";
        //if (TempData.ContainsKey(ErrorKey))
        //{
        //    ViewData[ErrorKey] = TempData[ErrorKey];
        //    TempData.Remove(ErrorKey);
        //}
        return View();
    }
```

Redirect doesn't fire the controller?

Comment: I'm determining whether or not it loads via a breakpoint at the bottom on the `return View();` line. Additionally the message doesn't show up. I tried using TempData but the message did not show up until I hit F5/refresh. So the index wasn't firing by that process either.

Comment: Is your controller that you are redirecting to called HomeController? Is it located in the Controllers folder as per convention?

Comment: yes, I haven't moved or touched the home controller that comes by default in a new mvc project. and the page loads, but it loads without going through the index controller, probably cached like Craig is suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You must use `TempData` when redirecting. `ViewData` *will not work* when set before a redirect.
2. Do you cache the site index? Does the browser cache it? Look at the request and response with Firebug or Fiddler.

Comment: if caching is the problem, how can I force a reload?

Comment: Depends who is caching it. The generic answer is "with request or response headers."

Comment: I'm in firebug but I don't see where to sort out who might be caching something. How would I change this `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");` to have it specify load a fresh copy for each?

Comment: 1) If you see a request, and a response from the server, then the browser isn't caching. If no request/response, then it is. 2) If a breakpoint in the action does not stop, then the web server is caching. If it does, then it isn't. 3) You can't "specify a fresh copy" in a redirect (except, perhaps, with a bogus query string param). You have to specify cache policy correctly to begin with.